# Error in div inside a third party library in React

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps

I have simple one screen app on React with map on this screen.
Map created via tutorials. Every time i get error message:

ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
in div (created by Map)

Map is a class from library - @vis.gl/react-google-maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkHNl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuJuJ.png)

its very confused me.

Comment: I think it is because you are using `div` instead of `View` since it is react native. Also, it will be better if you provide code blocks instead of image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also put a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as commented above, to improve your chances of getting help.

Comment: @YakupgulyMalikov in my code i removed all the divs, error points to div created by Map class from library

Comment: Then it might be only used for react apps not for react native.